How do I implement 2 different builds for my python project? One for uploading to pypi and another for local usage and mypycify optimizations
I have built a basic python project. The project at its core is using a toml file to store all the configurations and build rules (see below):
[project]
authors = [{ name = "name", email = "email@email.com" }]
name = "name"
version = "0.0.0"
description = "description"
readme = { file = "README.md", content-type = "text/markdown" }
license = { file = "LICENSE" }
keywords = ["key", "words"]
dependencies = ["requests", "filetype", "pypdf", "mypy", "types-requests"]
classifiers = [
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11",
    "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
    "Operating System :: Unix",
]

[project.urls]
Repository = "https://www.myrepo.com/"

[project.scripts]
scripts = "package_name.main:main"

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel", "mypy", "types-requests"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.black]
line-length = 120

[tool.isort]
line_length = 120
profile = "black"

[tool.mypy]
ignore_missing_imports = true

[tool.commitizen]
name = "cz_conventional_commits"
tag_format = "$version"
version_files = ["./pyproject.toml", "./package_name/_version.py:__version__"]
version_scheme = "semver"
version_provider = "pep621"
update_changelog_on_bump = true

I found the code execution is quite slow compared to something like Go and I wanted to achieve easy gains. So, I decided to build my project using mypycify. For this however I need to locate all the python files that I want to pass to mypycify using glob, therefore I need to have setup.py as part of my project build as well. The contents of setup.py are:
#!/usr/bin/env python

from glob import glob

from mypyc.build import mypycify
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

paths: list[str] = glob("package_name/**.py")
paths += glob("package_name/src/**.py")

setup(
    packages=find_packages(exclude=["*tests*"]),
    ext_modules=mypycify(paths),
)

Running python3 -m build with these configurations generates these files:

package_name-0.0.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_15_0_arm64.whl
package_name-0.0.0.tar.gz

Here is my issue. I need my project to build a wheel suitable for uploading to pypi for any system, not strictly for my own (as we generated above). To do this, I need to remove or comment out ext_modules=mypycify(paths), from setup.py and I generate:

package_name-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
package_name-0.0.0.tar.gz

Excellent! But what solution can I apply such that I can generate both? One for uploading to pypi, and another for when devs want to build locally with mypycify optimizations.
The easiest solution seems to be to have 2 packages with different names. One unique setup.py for each where the only difference is one has ext_modules=mypycify(paths), and the other does not. But this seems silly in my case as that line in setup.py would be the only difference.

"build a wheel suitable for uploading to pypi for any system" If your package contains C code you cannot have a universal wheel. Said C code must be compiled for any platform separately and uploaded to PyPI separately. Example (I'm the maintainer): https://pypi.org/project/CT3/#files . Or you can just upload sdist (package_name-0.0.0.tar.gz) and make your poor users to compile themselves.

@phd, yep there is no C code in the project. Only the code generated by mypycify. That code will not be pushed to pypi. But I do want the option available for any devs who want to run the project locally after they clone the repo.

Try python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal . Another example by me: https://pypi.org/project/SQLObject/#files

The above command generates the following: package_name-0.0.0-cp311-cp311-macosx_15_0_arm64.whl
It also does not generate a tar file that build generates.

This means that "there is no C code in the project." is not true. "Only the code generated by mypycify." It seems setuptools counted it too. I don't know any way to work around it. You need to go with platform-specific builds. To build an sdist: python setup.py sdist

There is no C code. The reason it generates the file above is because of setup.py still having the ext_modules=mypycify(paths) in setup.py. Commenting it out and then executing python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal will generate package_name-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.

ext_modules=mypycify(paths) This is surely C code. Wheels with Python extensions modules cannot be universal, they can only be platform-specific.

And that is my question. I want to generate 2 wheel files. One platform specific and one for all systems without having to create a whole separate project. What changes do I have to make to make both options available to the user of the repo?

Try two different setup.py files. Or a single setup.py file with a condition; pass a flag via environment what to build; use ext_modules or avoid it depending on the flag. ext_modules=mypycify(paths) if os.environ.get('MYPACKAGE_USE_MYPYC') else None. Build with MYPACKAGE_USE_MYPYC=1 python setup.py bdist_wheel or MYPACKAGE_USE_MYPYC="" python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal.
